# Checking Folder & subfolders

Tags: java, directory

I've made a method that checks 2 strings passed into itself that see's if a root folder and subfolder within it exists and if they don't, create them.

It's easy enough and it works well but my only issue is when I want to check for a root folder only it returns and error since one of the strings is empty.

Is there a smart way of checking for a path like `"/data"` , `"/data/files"` or `"/data/files/morefiles"` to see if all folders exists and if not, create the missing ones?

Comment: Please post the code that you've already wrote.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Create a folder if one doesn't exist](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14666170/create-a-folder-if-one-doesnt-exist)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is there a proper way to check for file/directory existence in Java?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7996524/is-there-a-proper-way-to-check-for-file-directory-existence-in-java)

Answer (score 3):

There is a ready-made method which creates all the missing parent directories: [`File#mkdirs()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/File.html#mkdirs%28%29).

Answer (score 1):

```
new File("/path/to/subdirectory").mkdirs();
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `.mkdirs()` method on any `File` object

```
// Create a directory; all non-existent ancestor directories are
// automatically created
success = (new File("../potentially/long/pathname/without/all/dirs")).mkdirs();
```

Answer (score 0):

you can take the string and split it using `split("\\");`
after that, build in a for statement the path, each time checking and creating the folder if needed

```
String path;// Your path, that you get as parameter
String[] pathArr = path.split("\\");
string str = pathArr[0];
int size = pathArr.size();

for(int i = 1; i <  size ; i++)
{
    // Check and create folder if needed
    str = str + "\\" + pathArr[i];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You will want to check out the [`File`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/File.html) api. Specifically:

[isDirectory()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/File.html#isDirectory%28%29)

[exists()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/File.html#exists%28%29)

[mkdirs()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/File.html#mkdirs%28%29)