# solaris 10, java 6 , file.exists cant see the existing file

Tags: java, solaris, ramdisk

i have a code that composes millions of small files into tar archives, and therefore i decided to use the /tmp folder of my solaris machine. then i created a ramdisk and instead of /tmp i now use ramdisk (/ramdata) i created.. 
here is what i did to accomplish the mission :

first i tried to create tar archive in ramdisk and then move to the target directory, but when i do so, java's File.exists() failed to return true when the file existed. then i changed the directory to a directory on disk (opt/dist/dist1/cdrepo) to put my tar file, and the tar file created successfully there but again File.exists() failed to return true when the file is there.

then i saw this post [Alternative to File.exists() in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3833127/alternative-to-file-exists-in-java)  and i changed my code accordingly so NFS will reset the cache, but it didnt work neither.

can anyone suggest any solution or idea about why it happens and how i can solve this problem? thanks to all.

i am using Java6U21, and it is a Solaris 10 machine..

below is the final code of my tryings.. : i know the code has some signs from my previous tryings -such as teh place where i instantiate a File object and check its existence with fileExists variable...- that will not definitely work as expected, but since for now i am just trying to see the true result for File.exists(), i ignore them. the main exception is in the line czf.take_md5 method, the first line of which is `FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(filename);`

```
public static synchronized void CreateZipFileFromSingleFolder(String folder,int CDNumber) throws Exception{

    CreateZipFile czf = new CreateZipFile();
        System.err.println(folder + " tarlaniyor...");
        Process p=null;

        String tarName=CDFolderInfo.getID()+"_cd_"+CDNumber + ".tar ";
        String tarFolder=CDFolderInfo.getPathRoot();
        //String komut = "tar -cf " + tarFolder+"/"+tarName+"  "+ folder;
        String komut = "tar -cf " + "/opt/dist/dist1/cdrepo/"+tarName+"  "+ folder;
        try {
            System.err.println(komut + " ----- komutu ile tarlama yapilacak.......");
            p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(komut);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        try {
            p.waitFor();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        System.err.println("system exit value:  "  + p.exitValue());
        if(p.exitValue()==0)
        {
                Process p3=null;
                p3=Runtime.getRuntime().exec("ls -l /opt/dist/dist1/cdrepo");
                p3.waitFor();
                if(p3.exitValue()==0)
                    System.err.println("LS CDREPO ICIN BASARILI OLARAK CALISTI...");

                /*Process p4=null;
                p4=Runtime.getRuntime().exec("ls -l " +tarFolder+"/"+tarName);
                p4.waitFor();
                if(p4.exitValue()==0)
                    System.err.println("LS TAR FOLDER ICIN BASARILI OLARAK CALISTI...");
                */

                File f2=new File("/opt/dist/dist1/cdrepo/"+tarName);

                System.err.println("Absolute Path : "+f2.getAbsolutePath());
                System.err.println("         Path : "+f2.getPath());
                System.err.println("Canonical Path : "+f2.getCanonicalPath());
                System.err.println("is File : "+f2.isFile());
                System.err.println("Length : "+f2.length());
                System.err.println("is Hidden : "+f2.isHidden());

                if(f2.exists())
                    System.err.println("Dosya cdrepoda...");
                else 
                    System.err.println("dosya derepoda degil...");
                f2=null;

                try {
                    czf.take_md5("/opt/dist/dist1/cdrepo/"+tarName);
                    System.err.println("MD5 alma succeed...");
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }



                /*
                if(f2.exists())
                    System.err.println("Tar tasima succeed..");
                else 
                    System.err.println("move komutu basarili , ama dosyayi bulamiyorum...");
                f2=null;*/



            }else
                System.err.println("p == 0 yanlis... Tar olusturma failed..");


            /*System.err.println("tar file existence will be checked..");*/
            File f=new File(tarFolder+"/"+tarName);
            boolean fileExists = FileUtils.waitFor(f, 10);
            if(fileExists){
                System.err.println("tar succeeded .... " + tarFolder+"/"+tarName);
                System.err.println("tar file existence PASSED ..");
            }else{
                System.err.println("tar process didnt fail, but actually failed...");
            }
            f=null;

        /*  Process p2 = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("mv " + tarFolder+"/"+tarName+"  "+ "cdrepo/"+tarName);
            p2.waitFor();*/

        //if(p2.exitValue()==0){
                //System.err.println("p2 == 0 kontrolu dogru....");
                Process p1=null;
                try {
                    p1 = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("rm -rf " + folder );
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                try {
                    p1.waitFor();
                    if(p1.exitValue()==0)
                        System.err.println("Dizin silme tamamlandı... " + folder);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }       
    //  }
}
```

and the output is :

```
    /ramdata/cdtemp_125_1 tarlaniyor...
tar -cf /opt/dist/dist1/cdrepo/125_cd_1.tar   /ramdata/cdtemp_125_1 ----- komutu ile tarlama yapilacak.......
system exit value:  0
LS CDREPO ICIN BASARILI OLARAK CALISTI...
Absolute Path : /opt/dist/dist1/cdrepo/125_cd_1.tar 
         Path : /opt/dist/dist1/cdrepo/125_cd_1.tar 
Canonical Path : /opt/dist/dist1/cdrepo/125_cd_1.tar 
is File : false
Length : 0
is Hidden : false
dosya derepoda degil...
java.io.FileNotFoundException: /opt/dist/dist1/cdrepo/125_cd_1.tar  (No such file or directory)
        at java.io.FileInputStream.open(Native Method)
        at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:106)
        at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:66)
        at staticcdbuildernewver.CreateZipFile.take_md5(CreateZipFile.java:34)
        at staticcdbuildernewver.OracleSideDbOps.CreateZipFileFromSingleFolder(OracleSideDbOps.java:723)
```

AND THIS IS THE OUTPUT OF THE TRUSS command that Jayan suggested : 
it seems it cant resolve path :( but as i am not good in UNIX linux, i cant pretty much understand what it means..

```
/37:    1179.9948       write(2, " L S   C D R E P O   I C".., 41)      = 41
/21:    1179.9948       lwp_cond_wait(0x08234D48, 0x08234D30, 0xB60D6C08, 0) = 0
/21:    1179.9949       mprotect(0xFEC60000, 4096, PROT_READ)           = 0
/37:    1179.9950           Incurred fault #6, FLTBOUNDS  %pc = 0xFE4B49A1
/37:          siginfo: SIGSEGV SEGV_ACCERR addr=0xFEC60280
/37:    1179.9950           Received signal #11, SIGSEGV [caught]
/37:          siginfo: SIGSEGV SEGV_ACCERR addr=0xFEC60280
/21:    1179.9950       mprotect(0xFEC60000, 4096, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE) = 0
/37:    1179.9950       lwp_sigmask(SIG_SETMASK, 0xFFBFFEFF, 0x0000FFF7) = 0xFFBFFEFF [0x0000FFFF]
/37:    1179.9951       setcontext(0xB5A6C1C0)
/21:    1179.9951       mprotect(0xFEE20000, 4096, PROT_NONE)           = 0
/21:    1179.9957       mprotect(0xFEE20000, 4096, PROT_READ)           = 0
/21:    1179.9958       lwp_cond_signal(0x0849D448)                     = 0
/37:    1179.9958       lwp_cond_wait(0x0849D448, 0x0849D430, 0x00000000, 0) = 0
/21:    1179.9959       lwp_cond_signal(0x084BDC48)                     = 0
/39:    1179.9959       lwp_cond_wait(0x084BDC48, 0x084BDC30, 0x00000000, 0) = 0
/37:    1179.9959       write(2, "\n", 1)                               = 1
/39:    1179.9959       mprotect(0xB5BDC000, 12288, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE) = 0
/37:    1179.9960       write(2, " / o p t / d i s t / d i".., 15)      = 15
/39:    1179.9960       lwp_sigmask(SIG_SETMASK, 0x00000004, 0x00000000) = 0xFFBFFEFF [0x0000FFFF]
/37:    1179.9961       write(2, "\n", 1)                               = 1
/39:    1179.9961       lwp_sigmask(SIG_SETMASK, 0xFFBFFEFF, 0x0000FFF7) = 0xFFBFFEFF [0x0000FFFF]
/37:    1179.9962       write(2, "\n", 1)                               = 1
/39:    1179.9962       lwp_exit()
/37:    1179.9963       write(2, " / o p t / d i s t / d i".., 15)      = 15
/37:    1179.9964       write(2, "\n", 1)                               = 1
/37:    1179.9964       write(2, "\n", 1)                               = 1
/37:    1179.9965       write(2, " A b s o l u t e   P a t".., 52)      = 52
/37:    1179.9966       write(2, "\n", 1)                               = 1
/37:    1179.9967       write(2, "                   P a t".., 52)      = 52
/37:    1179.9967       write(2, "\n", 1)                               = 1
/37:    1179.9968       resolvepath("/opt/dist/dist1/cdrepo/125_cd_1.tar ", 0xB5A6C3C0, 1024) Err#2 ENOENT
/37:    1179.9969       resolvepath("/opt/dist/dist1/cdrepo", "/opt/dist/dist1/cdrepo", 1024) = 22
/37:    1179.9970       write(2, " C a n o n i c a l   P a".., 53)      = 53
/37:    1179.9970       write(2, "\n", 1)                               = 1
/37:    1179.9971       stat64("/opt/dist/dist1/cdrepo/125_cd_1.tar ", 0xB5A6C6C0) Err#2 ENOENT
/37:    1179.9972       write(2, " i s   F i l e   :   f a".., 15)      = 15
/37:    1179.9972       write(2, "\n", 1)                               = 1
/37:    1179.9973       stat64("/opt/dist/dist1/cdrepo/125_cd_1.tar ", 0xB5A6C700) Err#2 ENOENT
/37:    1179.9974       write(2, " L e n g t h   :   0", 10)            = 10
/37:    1179.9975       write(2, "\n", 1)                               = 1
/37:    1179.9975       stat64("/opt/dist/dist1/cdrepo/125_cd_1.tar ", 0xB5A6C6C0) Err#2 ENOENT
/37:    1179.9976       write(2, " i s   H i d d e n   :  ".., 17)      = 17
/37:    1179.9977       write(2, "\n", 1)                               = 1
/37:    1179.9977       write(2, " / o p t / d i s t / d i".., 15)      = 15
/37:    1179.9978       write(2, "\n", 1)                               = 1
/37:    1179.9979       write(2, "\n", 1)                               = 1
/37:    1179.9979       stat64("/opt/dist/dist1/cdrepo/125_cd_1.tar ", 0xB5A6C700) Err#2 ENOENT
/37:    1179.9980       write(2, " d o s y a   d e r e p o".., 23)      = 23
/37:    1179.9980       write(2, "\n", 1)                               = 1
/37:    1179.9981       open64("/opt/dist/dist1/cdrepo/125_cd_1.tar ", O_RDONLY) Err#2 ENOENT
/37:    1179.9983       write(2, " j a v a . i o . F i l e".., 95)      = 95
/37:    1179.9984       write(2, "\n", 1)                               = 1
/37:    1179.9986       write(2, "\t a t   j a v a . i o .".., 47)      = 47
/37:    1179.9986       write(2, "\n", 1)                               = 1
/37:    1179.9987       write(2, "\t a t   j a v a . i o .".., 60)      = 60
/37:    1179.9987       write(2, "\n", 1)                               = 1
/37:    1179.9988       write(2, "\t a t   j a v a . i o .".., 59)      = 59
/37:    1179.9988       write(2, "\n", 1)                               = 1
/37:    1179.9989       write(2, "\t a t   s t a t i c c d".., 71)      = 71
/37:    1179.9990       write(2, "\n", 1)                               = 1
/37:    1179.9990       write(2, "\t a t   s t a t i c c d".., 97)      = 97
/37:    1179.9991       write(2, "\n", 1)                               = 1
/37:    1179.9991       write(2, "\t a t   s t a t i c c d".., 68)      = 68
/37:    1179.9992       write(2, "\n", 1)                               = 1
/37:    1179.9993       write(2, "\t a t   s t a t i c c d".., 87)      = 87
/37:    1179.9993       write(2, "\n", 1)                               = 1
/37:    1179.9994       write(2, "\t a t   s t a t i c c d".., 55)      = 55
/37:    1179.9995       write(2, "\n", 1)                               = 1
/37:    1179.9995       write(2, "\t a t   j a v a . l a n".., 41)      = 41
```

Comment: Could it be that Solaris user does not have enough access rights to get the file listing in the directory?

Comment: i use this java program from a ssh connection window, and i connect with root user.. is there any case when root will not have directory listing rights ?

Comment: Ramdisks are not NFS-mounted.

Comment: i am not good at Linux UNIX systems, i just saw that post and tried just in case.. :)

Comment: could you run the command with truss <command> and see if any thing make sense..

Comment: this is the first time i hear of truss command, i used it and it is now running, but how should i interpret those pretty low level, at least for me, indications ?

Comment: well, all the problem lies in the extra space in the defitinion of tarName variable.. just removed the extra space and now everything works fine.. thanks to everyone who had suggestions..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

all the problem lies in the extra space in the defitinion of tarName variable.. just remove the extra space.. and everything will work fine..

Answer (score 0):

Only a try

```
if(f2.exists())
     System.err.println("Dosya cdrepoda...");
else {
     System.err.println("dosya derepoda degil...");
     f2.getParentFile().mkdirs();
}
```

Comment: all the needed directories are pre-created.. but i want f2.exists() return true, in this case you just make an act when it is false which means i will still have the error.. if i misunderstood please clarify..