# File exists returns wrong value

Tags: java

In my program I am dealing with files moved by other applications to a common shared mount point in NFS. In around 0.01% of the time my `File.exists()` check fails saying that the file does not exists, but when I try a `ls -l` on the directory I can see the file seating there. Any reason for such a behavior and how to rectify it.

Comment: show some code please

Comment: How are you making sure the file didn't appear between the time your code checks and the time you run ls?

Comment: elaborate your question or we would not be able to help you.

Comment: Here is the code: `File f = new File(filePath); if(f.exists()){...}else{logger.info("No file exists")` In few occasions the else part gets executed, and when I get that in the log I try to check in few minutes time to see if the file is actually not there using `ls`

Comment: Wel I got something here <a>http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3833127/alternative-to-file-exists-in-java</a> it seems to be a NFS issue. But is there any alternatives.

Comment: Not sure whether it will help but have you thought about trying something like Apache Commons VFS http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-vfs another option would be to try using JNI/JNA.

Comment: Thats something new to me ! But are you saying VFS will not have the same issues that I am facing because of NFS ?